# Does Android Enthusiasts support embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

[Over on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462), I am attempting to compile a complete list of Stack Exchange sites which support YouTube embedding.

Searching on Android Enthusiasts Meta, I was unable to find any discussion of whether embedded YouTube videos are supported. Because [YouTube embedding is not shown in the markdown preview window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299082/display-embedded-youtube-videos-in-markdown-preview), there's no way to test without posting publically.

**Are embedded YouTube videos supported on Android Enthusiasts?**

Comment: Embedding is enabled by request. If it was never even discussed, it's not enabled. I hope you don't plan to post this on 160  metas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's only one way to find out.

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>

Comment: So it seems Android.SE was sensitive enough to not enable this? Though it might seem inconvenient, that's good for privacy: every visitor can chose whether to have his/her IP tracked by Google :)

Comment: @Izzy I believe YT embedding is disabled on most sites by default, but can be enabled if a site's community [specifically requests it](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1736/21792).

Comment: While that request is mostly ignored, as you found out in the linked post. Never mind, different ideologies (tin foils versus cloud junkies – and some folks "between the lines"). Just wanted to point out both variants have their pros and cons, no "ratings" implied :)